# cefSharp Detect when entire page is loaded

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I need to be able to detect when an entire page is loaded. The page has JavaScript that executes when you browse to it as well. And I must wait for that to finish loading as it adds HTML Elements to the page.

I have tried the below event. But this is trigger when the main page loads and doesn't care about the javascript.

```
 browser.LoadingStateChanged
```

So I also tried count these to know when all the frames on a page where loaded. But it still wasn't spot on.

```
 browser.FrameLoadStart += OnFrameLoadStart;
 browser.FrameLoadEnd += OnFrameLoadEnd;
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Overall what are you trying to achieve? If your new to `CefSharp`, then start by reading https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage it covers many topics, like when you can execute javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Ended up using javascript to wait for element to display and then continue